# Several instances of a common @Configuration with different @PropertySource in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Hi I have the following configuration file :

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:english.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:spanish.properties")
})
public class LanguageConfig {

    @Value(${hello})
    private String hello;

    // getter setter
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to **Autowire** two instances of **LanguageConfig**, one for each language. Something like :

```java
public Myservice() {

    @Autowire
    @Qualifier("englishLanguage")
    private LanguageConfig englishConfig;


    @Autowire
    @Qualifier("spanishLanguage")
    private LanguageConfig spanishConfig;


}
```

Thank you.

Comment: As you are using spring boot, I'd advise you check configuration properties for better handling of this.

Comment: Also smells like something best used with i18n features such as `MessageBundle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do can be achieved or not, but I offer you this solution.

Instead of having each language in separate files, you can put them in a single file, let's say `languages.properties`, and then add it using `@PropertySource("classpath:language.properties")` annotation. After that you can inject those properties using `@ConfigurationProperties`.

```
en.hello=Hello
sp.hello=Hola
```

LanguageConfig class should look like this.

```java
public class LanguageConfig {

    private String hello;

    public String getHello() {
        return hello;
    }

    public void setHello(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }
}
```

Create those `LanguageConfig` objects as beans and inject properties starting with `en` and `sp` to each of them.

```java
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("en")
    public LanguageConfig engConfig() {
        return new LanguageConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("sp")
    public LanguageConfig spanishConfig() {
        return new LanguageConfig();
    }
```

Then you can use them easily.

```java
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("engConfig")
    LanguageConfig englishConfig;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("spanishConfig")
    LanguageConfig spanishConfig;
```

Comment: You could embed this to one `language` class with `en` and `sp` being members of the `language` class which has a field of `hello` which might simplify it a bit. Not the original question, but would be cleaner