# Configuration inheritance in Spring Boot and different property sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inheritance, autowired

Using Spring Boot and inheritance with configuration classes, I am trying to do something like this :

```
@Getter // Lombok annotation to automatically generate getters
@Setter // Same for setters
public abstract class AbstractConfiguration {

    @Value("${hello}")
    protected String hello;
}


@Configuration
@Qualifier(name = "en")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:hello_en.properties")
public class EnglishConfiguration extends AbstractConfiguration {

}

@Configuration
@Qualifier(name = "fr")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:hello_fr.properties")
public class FrenchConfiguration extends AbstractConfiguration {

}
```

With property files :

**hello_en.properties**

```
hello=Hello !
```

**hello_fr.properties**

```
hello=Bonjour !
```

And then somewhere else in the code I would use configuration classes in this manner :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(name = "en")
private AbstractConfiguration englishConfiguration;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(name = "fr")
private AbstractConfiguration frenchConfiguration;


.....

public void test() {

    System.out.println(englishConfiguration.getHello()); // Should print "Hello !"

    System.out.println(frenchConfiguration.getHello()); // Should print "Bonjour !"
}
```

Basically the idea would be that as more languages are added, I would just need to add a new XXXXConfiguration class with a matching new property source, and not refactor or alter any of the code that has been previously written. I believe I am trying to apply the Open/Closed principle of S.O.L.I.D.

The current example is not working, what are the mistakes I've made ? How can I improve the code to be as clean as possible please ? Is there anything I have not understood about `@Configuration` and `@Qualifier` ?

Also, is there any difference between writing `@Configuration(name = "en")` and `@Configuration @Qualifier(name = "en")` ?

Thank you in advance for your help dear readers.

Comment: Don't you think there are better approaches to achieve internationalization (i18n) ?

Comment: Surely there are but I'll admit I'm not familiar with any, I just thought I could reuse my current knowledge and apply it to this use case. Any suggestions :) ? Besides, appart from achieving i18n correctly, I'm really interested in understanding how I could make the example work even if it's just for the sake of it.

Comment: Check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905741/9985287

Comment: Oh i see so you are using only one property source along with @ConfigurationProperties ! Thank you so much :)
Leaving the issue open for now to see if there are other ways to do it !